# How is a server restart handled in Cadence?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

How does the server restart functionality work during the deployment of code in Cadence? What will be restarted? Will it restart only the Cadence service or does it restart the workers as well? If the workers are restarted, will the activities and workflows get restarted from the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

Restarting server doesn’t necessarily restart the application workers. They should be managed by different deployment groups.

Server restarting doesn’t impact any workflow or activity restarting.

Restarting worker may cause some activity task to restart. Therefore, it’s recommended to set appropriate retry policy/options to activity.

Restarting worker won’t cause any restart to workflow.